# Difference between playwright `toBeVisible` and `toBeInViewport`

Tags: javascript, testing, playwright, playwright-test

Using `toBeVisible`:

```js
const locator = page.locator('.my-element');
await expect(locator).toBeVisible();
```

Using `toBeInViewport`:

```js
const locator = page.locator('.my-element');
await expect(locator).toBeInViewport();
```

**What is the difference here? both of them are testing if the element is visible to user.**

If both of them are different, then what is the use case for each of them?

Comment: This is a interesting topic not only for playwright , but also for UI automation in general.

Answer (score 1):

[How is `Visible` defined in Playwright:](https://playwright.dev/docs/actionability#visible)

> Element is considered visible when it has non-empty bounding box and does not have visibility:hidden computed style. Note that elements of zero size or with display:none are not considered visible.

Thus, something `Visible` may not be actually 'visible' by a real user, or say, **may not intersects with the `Viewport`**.